Prove that: $x = \sum_{i, j\in I} x_{i, j} \otimes e_{i,j}$
Let $\mathcal{H}, \mathcal{K}$ are Hilbert spaces and $(\epsilon_i)_{i\in I}$ be an ONB for $\mathcal{K}$. Suppose for each $i\in I, U_i:\mathcal{H}\to \mathcal{H} \otimes\mathcal{K}$ is the isometry defined by $U_i\xi:=\xi\otimes \epsilon_i$ for $\xi \in \mathcal{H}$. Also for $i, j\in I$ we define $e_{i, j}\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{K})$ by $e_{i,j}\zeta:=\langle\zeta, \epsilon_j\rangle \epsilon_i$.
Now let $x\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H} \otimes \mathcal{K})$ and $x_{i, j}:= U_i^*xU_j $ for $i, j \in I$. Then I want to prove the following:

Claim. $x = \sum_{i, j\in I} x_{i, j} \otimes e_{i,j}$ where this sum is considered under SOT.

Let $\sum_{k=1}^n \xi_k \otimes \eta_k \in \mathcal{H}\otimes \mathcal{K}$. I need to show that $\left(\sum_{i, j\in I} x_{i, j} \otimes e_{i,j}\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \xi_k \otimes \eta_k\right) = x \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \xi_k \otimes \eta_k\right)$.
For a simple tensor $\xi\otimes \eta \in \mathcal{H} \otimes \mathcal{K}$ we've:
$(x_{i, j}\otimes e_{i, j})(\xi \otimes \eta) = (U_i^*x U_j \xi) \otimes \langle \eta, \epsilon_j\rangle \epsilon_i$
But it doesn't help much.
